# Can a work submitted to linux workqueue schedule itself

Tags: c, linux, kernel, workqueue

PFB the pseudo code:

```c
struct work_struct my_work;

my_wq = alloc_workqueue();

INIT_WORK(&my_work, worker_func);

void worker_func() {

  if (condition)
      queue_work(my_wq, my_work);

}
```

Is this allowed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly allowed to re-submit a work while its function is executed.

It is also allowed to de-allocate the work structure which function is executed.
Workqueue implementation is ready for that ([kernel/workqueue.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/kernel/workqueue.c#L2090)):

> It is permissible to free the struct work_struct from
> inside the function that is called from it, this we need to
> take into account for lockdep too...